# How to move an object in XNA so that it does not jiggle?

Tags: silverlight, xna

i want to know how can i move a object that it dont jiggle in XNA?
my code just decrease the Y position by 1 in each update call. but this looks very ugly because it jiggle, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(0,100); // Pixels x Second
Vector2 Position = ScreenCenter;

public void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    float Seconds = (float) gametime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    Position += Speed * Seconds;
}
```

Comment: this let the object move in one direction but it dont looks like a continuing movement because it stucks some time and have a jitter.

Comment: i think you are testing in windows, set IsFixedTimeStep = false and graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false.